# Bidirectional synchronization with Local Json file and Firebase Realtime

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a python project and I was wondering how can I do a bidirectional sync between a local json file and firebase realtime db. I keep getting a problem where if I try to change key-pair value in my json file, It wont be passed in the Firebase realtime db and reverts back the old value. But If I change the key-pair using Firebase console, The value is passed to my json file.

I made a function to read, update, and recursively update nested data in the local JSON file and return the data.

```
def read_local_data():
    with open('ElectricRPI.json', 'r') as f:
        return json.load(f)

def update_local_data(data):
    with open('ElectricRPI.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)

def update_nested_data(local_data, new_data):
    if isinstance(new_data, dict):
        for key, value in new_data.items():
            if key in local_data and isinstance(value, dict):
                local_data[key] = update_nested_data(local_data[key], value)
            else:
                local_data[key] = value
    return local_data

updating_from_firebase = False
```

Then I made a functions to handle updates from the JSON file to Firebase and vice versa.

```
def firebase_to_json():
    global updating_from_firebase

    local_data = read_local_data()

    firebase_data = ref.get()
    if firebase_data != local_data:
        print('Change detected in the Firebase database')

        updating_from_firebase = True
        local_data = update_nested_data(local_data, firebase_data)
        updating_from_firebase = False


        if not updating_from_firebase:
            update_local_data(local_data)

def json_to_firebase():
    global updating_from_firebase

    local_data = read_local_data()

    firebase_data = ref.get()
    if local_data != firebase_data:
        print('Change detected in the local JSON file')

        if not updating_from_firebase:
            ref.set(local_data)

ref = db.reference('/')
```

I was expecting that this would help me fix some problems where If there's no internet connectivity, the data will first be store in the local json file and will be passed on the firebase and vice-versa.